# how to unpark parked domain in whm cpanel

Tags: php, curl, cpanel, whm

i have a problem deleting parked domains with api from whm

i already have api to added the domains and it's worked great but when i try to delete them with php curl also it's won't working

this is the code

```
    $api       = "https://" . whm_domain . ":2087/json-api/delete_domain?api.version=2";
    $curl      = curl_init();
                 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api);
                 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(
                 [
                     "domain" => $_POST["domain"]
                 ]));
                 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Authorization: whm " . whm_username . ":" . whm_token]);
                 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    $response  = curl_exec($curl);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                 curl_close($curl);

    if ($http_code !== 200 || !is_json($response))
    {
        http_response_code(400);
        exit(json_encode(["status" => "error", "response" => $lang["response-error"]]));
    }
    else
    {
        $response = json_decode($response, true);

        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE || ($response["metadata"]["result"] ?? 0) !== 1)
        {
            http_response_code(400);
            exit(json_encode(["status" => "error", "response" => json_encode($response)]));
        }
    }
```

and this is the retuned json

{"status":"error","response":"{"metadata":{"version":1,"result":0,"reason":"Permission denied: You do not have the required privileges to run \u201cdelete_domain\u201d.","command":"delete_domain"}}"}

**ps:** username and token are correct they work on the added api code

Comment: user does not have privilege to delete domain, response message didn't said anything about authentication failure.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run the command as root, since the user you are attempting with does not have privileges.